# Handling multiple users and concurrency in Node.JS Apps

Tags: node.js, express, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I recently developed a Teams Node.JS app for one of my clients. I'm very new to Node development, so I need some help on the following.

- The app will be used by hundreds of users. I haven't done anything special to handle concurrency. I use a combination of node and express. Will these two handle concurrency and multi-threading automatically?
- The app makes heavy use of Microsoft Graph, and occasionally for no reason at all, graph calls fails with 503 errors. Upon retrying after some time, it starts working again, but this behavior seems repeating off late. What could be the problem?
- I've hosted the app on Azure App Service and set it to auto-scale. Is there any other configuration required to handle additional users?

Comment: Please remember that SO is [for programming problems](on-topic), not really for "teaching you about specific programming environments" - for your first point, what does "a combination of Node and Express" mean? Express is server software, Node is your programming environment with a low level standard library that really shouldn't need because express will have done it better. As for the second, without an [mcve] or at the very least many more details, that's [not a question](/help/how-to-ask) yet. And finally, the third one is definitely something you should be able to just search the web for.

Comment: An app hosted on azure can be used by n number of users, are you facing any particular issue here? Please  share more details with the issue with Graph API.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT My concern is about concurrency when multiple users are accessing graph at the same time from my app. Occasionally I get 503 errors from graph and not sure if it's an issue with concurrency.

Comment: Could you please share the request body you are sending?